# Why we use Runnable interface?

Tags: java

Why we we use Runnable interface even it has no connection with `start()` method? Why we can't just write `run()` method and start?

Why we need to implement `run()` method,instead of using it directly and start process using `start()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @khelwood: Actually I think it's more basic than that. :-)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you show what you would want to write instead of using Runnable?

Comment: There is a connection between `run` and `start`: The thread that was just created by `start` immediately calls `run`.

Comment: Good point, I think 'run' is a bit of a misnomer. That method should have been called 'onStart()' or something. It's not a method you call yourself, but rather something you have to implement. And the Thread controls it's lifecycle.

Comment: The `Runnable` interface does not have a `start` method.

Answer (score 9):

If you just called the `run` method directly, it would run on the thread you used to call it. By implementing `Runnable` and passing your instance into `new Thread`, you're setting it up so that `run` will be called *on the new thread*.

I recommend working your way through the [Java Concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), which will go into creating and running threads in detail.